# Runtime xib downloading?

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode, ios

Is there any chance to runtime xib loading from remote server? Or i need to compile into the build? And if its possible, how can I add remote image resouces in interface builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed Bundles could be used but after checking with [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW30) again, it looks like you can't use this. It makes sense. Apple wouldn't want you extend your app's functionality without them reviewing it. Malicious behavior could compromise security too.

So, I doubt you will be able to do this.

Comment: iTunesConnect approve this solution?

Comment: I think the answer is no. Updated my answer based on that.

Comment: Thanks anyway. Conclusion: if I want to change the outfit for easter/chrismas/etc. special edition, I need to upload it for review again? I need to schedulde a new review for weeks before? It's useless, if the application business logic not changed...

Comment: By the way if you take a look at WeCity it updates itself on runtime? It's just loads images?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. You can't add functionality though. Check this solution here:

[loading NSBundle files on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203109/loading-nsbundle-files-on-ios)

Worth noting - WeCity probably has a javascript interpreter in it that allows for what you are seeing. Building that is a lot more complicated though.