# loading NSBundle files on iOS

Tags: ios, loading, nsbundle

I'd like to create a project that has a very flexible graphical user interface (*skinnable*). In order to make this possible, I'd like to load a NSBundle from an external resource, e.g. a website. The bundle should contain nibs that correspond to some properties and methods in the main project (IBOutlets & IBActions)

It seems Apple has limited the possibility to use NSBundle in such a way. Is there any way I can make this work? If it's not possible in the conventional way, what would be a recommendable alternate approach?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

untested.

You can distribute all the content in a zip file, unzip using [SSZipArchive](https://github.com/samsoffes/ssziparchive).

```
NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:absolutePathToNibFile].

UIViewController* vc = [[[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"mycustomnib" bundle:bundle] autorelease];
```

Comment: Well, I finally got a NSBundle to load from the documentsDirectory by copying it from the finder to the iPhone Simulator folder for the app, so it probably should work on a real device as well. To actually copy the file from the server it seems I have to archive the bundle in a zip it seems, so I'll accept your answer. **Edit:** I'll post the full code in this topic once I got everything working.

Comment: I have used SSZipArchive for distributing html content and it seems like a fairly robust component. It can extract really big zip files (those I tested with was around 40 mb) on an iPhone 3 without exhausting the memory.

Answer (score 34):

As promised, here a short explanation on how I made it work.

In my AppDelegate I check if there's a new bundle (packaged in a zip file) on the server. If it exists, I download the bundle. The bundle contains the nibs I need for my skinnable graphical interface and other related data (e.g. graphic files). The code looks a bit like this:

**TestAppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)downloadBundle 
{      
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1/~wsc/template.bundle.zip"];
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   NSURLResponse *response = nil;
   NSError *error = nil;
   NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
   NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
   NSLog(@"%d", [httpResponse statusCode]);

   if ([httpResponse statusCode] == 404) // bundle will be deleted and the default interface will be used ...
   {
      NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"template.bundle"];
      [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:nil];
      return;
   }
   else if (error) 
   {
      NSLog(@"%@", error);
   }

   BOOL didWriteData = [data writeToFile:zipFile atomically:YES];
   if (didWriteData) 
   {
      BOOL success = [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:zipFile toDestination:documentsDirectory];
      if (!success) 
      {
         NSLog(@"failed to unzip file.");
      }
   }
}
```

Please note I make use of the SSZipArchive class as suggested by *neoneye*. It's required to package the bundle in some sort of container to download all contents efficiently, since a bundle is just a directory & file structure following Apple's conventions.

One of my classes is a ViewController that has a label and button as IBOutlets. The most important code in the ViewController looks like this:

**TestViewController.h**

```
@interface TestViewController : UIViewController {
   UIButton *button;
   UILabel *label;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

- (IBAction)buttonTouched:(id)sender;

@end
```

**TestViewController.m**

```
@implementation TestViewController
@synthesize button, label;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

// the -init method is overridden to use nib file from bundle, if bundle exists ...
- (id)init 
{
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"template.bundle"];
   NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:file];
   if (!bundle)
   {
      NSLog(@"no bundle found, falling back to default gui ...");
      return [self initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
   }

   NSString *nibName = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
   return [self initWithNibName:nibName bundle:bundle];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
   [button release];
   [label release];
   [view release];

   [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)loadView
{
   if (self.nibName && self.nibBundle) 
   {
      // connect outlets to proxy objects ...
      NSDictionary *objects = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
          self.label, @"label", 
          self.button, @"button", 
          nil];
      NSDictionary *proxies = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:objects forKey:UINibExternalObjects];
      NSArray *nibs = [self.nibBundle loadNibNamed:self.nibName owner:self options:proxies]; // connection happens here ...

      NSLog(@"nibs found with name %@: %d", self.nibName, [nibs count]);
      return;
   }

   // show default gui if no nib was found ...

   CGRect frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
   self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
   [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

   self.button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
   [self.button setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 60.0f, 30.0f)];
   [self.button setCenter:CGPointMake(160.0f, 100.0f)];
   [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [self.view addSubview:self.button];

   self.label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, 30.0f)] autorelease];
   [self.label setCenter:CGPointMake(160.0f, 50.0f)];
   [self.label setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
   [self.view addSubview:self.label];
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   // for my purposes I'll add the localized string from the mainBundle here for the standard controls, 
   // this will override the text set in the nibs, since the nibs are loaded and displayed at this point ...
   [self.button setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"TestButton", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [self.label setText:NSLocalizedString(@"TestLabel", nil)];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
   [super viewDidUnload];
   self.button = nil;
   self.label = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark -

- (IBAction)buttonTouched:(id)sender 
{
   [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"DialogTitle", nil) 
                                message:NSLocalizedString(@"ButtonTouchedText", nil) 
                               delegate:nil 
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                      otherButtonTitles:nil] 
     autorelease] show];
}

@end
```

The actual nib is defined in a seperate linked project (Cocoa NSBundle project with some parameters changed to make it work for iOS devices). The file's owner is TestViewController, so I can access all outlets & actions and make the appropriate connections. Please note there's no *view* (UIView *) property defined in TestViewController, since the superclass already has a *view* property. Make sure the view is connected in Interface Builder. Also note the nib file makes use of the same name as the actual class for ease of use.

*Couldn't find much information on the web on how to do this, so I hope this will be helpful to lots of people that have similar goals.*

Comment: Nice. Also to download content I can recommend https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/tree  it does it in a separate thread, allowing you to show a progressbar while waiting for it to complete.

Comment: Excellent code! I'm having some issues though. How do you instantiate an instance of this view controller? If I try to init with the custom nib name, it looks in the main bundle and it's not there. If I try to init with a default nib, it can't load the bundle. Mind adding the last piece to this puzzle? :)

Comment: Also if I have outlets connected in the version I download, do I need to reapply them as you do in loadView()? Thanks!

Comment: Yes you do, that's the way to connect the proxy objects in your code with the objects in the nib file. I don't believe it'll work well without making the connections manually in code.

Comment: @mark: The default `-init` method is overridden to look for a nib with the same name as the viewController in a bundle called *template.bundle* (in de documents directory). So don't call `-initWithNibName:bundle:`, call `-init` instead. Perhaps I should override `-initWithNibName:bundle` to prevent such mistakes.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for speedy response! Will try it soon and report back. Thanks again!!!

Comment: Okay changed it to alloc init the view controller only, and updated name of my xib that's being downloaded to be the same as the class name. Getting a SIGABRT on this line: NSArray *nibs = [self.nibBundle loadNibNamed:self.nibName owner:self options:proxies];. Error: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle <[...]/Documents/gg.bundle> (not yet loaded)' with name 'ClassNameViewController''. How is the bundle "not yet loaded"?

Comment: Do you have this sample project hosted anywhere? That might help too. :)

Comment: I'll try to clean up the sample project and host it from my Dropbox.

Comment: Thanks! That will hopefully help me figure out what I am doing wrong!

Comment: Another thought - could I have set up my bundle incorrectly and that's why it's not loading. I just made a folder called gg.bundle, showed it's contents, added my xib file and then compressed it.

Comment: @mark: that might be the issue, I created a Mac OS X bundle project (under `Framework & Library`) and changed some properties of the project. The project is based on Core Foundation, since the Cocoa framework isn't available on iOS. The base SDK is set to `iOS (Latest)` and the Architecture to ARM.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the help Wolfgang! I have found that actions are carrying over if I hook them up before compiling the bundle. It seems like IBOutlets do not share the same benefit. All-in-all not a bad way to get "skinnable" UI. Thanks again! Cheers!

Comment: Nice - I'm sorry I didn't find the time to setup a demo project. I'm quite busy with work, so I really have to do stuff like that in the little spare time I have in the weekends, which isn't always possible for me.

Comment: No worries Wolfgang! Your example code and diligent checking back on comments (which I fail at) was plenty help! Thanks again!

Comment: Anyone know if this is considered legitimate with the app store approval policies?  Interested in using this technique myself.