# iOS - is it possible to download bundles from the internet with updated xibs?

Tags: ios, bundle, updates

I want to be able to customize xibs in my app after the app is released by changing xibs, bundling them, downloading that bundle and having the client configured to look in those new bundles for the new xibs.

So far, I have added a xib to a bundle I created and am attempting to download it:

```
   // bundle URL is NSURL to uploaded resource for bundle
   NSBundle *myBundle = [[NSBundle bundleWithURL:bundleURL] retain];
```

I get this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSBundle initWithURL:]: non-file URL argument'
```

My question: is it possible to do what I set out to do? This error suggests it is not possible.

If it isn't possible to download bundles, would it be possible to download just a xib and use that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203109/loading-nsbundle-files-on-ios), you can load a bundle with just XIBs, images, and other assets. Don't try to load a bundle with code in it, Apple has explicit checks for their digital signature if you try to load code, which would cause the load to fail.

Comment: @RyanR How do you know for sure that Apple has explicit checks for apps that try to load code? You are saying that "the load will fail". Does that mean that Apple will approve the app, but when it tries to load an NSBundle it will fail?

Comment: @Roberto That is the entire purpose of the walled garden that is iOS. Apple has designed the system to ensure nobody can run code that isn't signed (which is why the approval process we all love to hate is necessary). It's also [documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html) that you cannot create framework bundles for iOS. I tried to do it a few versions ago and it resulted in an exception. I'm pretty sure they scan for that during approval as well.

Comment: @JoelTeply Perhaps if you elaborated the comment would be more constructive?

Comment: Ok. If you swizzle your code properly, you can get around apple checks

Comment: @JoelTeply Please explain how method swizzling circumvents code signature checks

Comment: in C++ call memory buffer through a function pointer, while putting the compiled code in a png file or any other binary. Extract it, unmix it, stick it in a buffer, and then run it.

Answer (score 5):

You are getting this error because a bundle is stored as a folder in the file system. You can download a file easily, but you can't download a folder. NSBundle knows this, so it only allows local file URLs for initialization. You have three options for downloading bundles:

1. As mentioned in the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203109/loading-nsbundle-files-on-ios/6203329#6203329), you can download the bundle as a zip archive and unarchive it.
2. You can store an extra file on the server which lists the file names for each file in the bundle, and create it locally by downloading each file.
3. You can specify a format which will be used by all bundles, and download those files from the bundle. This is similar to 2, but has the list of file names built in instead of on the server.

Comment: Got it! Am following through on that link. Thanks!