# Loading External Bundle Files allowed?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uistoryboard, nsbundle

We are trying to load external NSBundle files remotely using a technique similar to below

[loading NSBundle files on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203109/loading-nsbundle-files-on-ios)

Does anyone know whether apple allow you to do this?

I assume as long as you don't change the functionality it is allowed?

Thanks for all your help

Comment: You can download external files as long as they do not contain code (jpg, wav, etc.). If it is contained within your bundle, you can load whatever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ask Apple to be sure, but probably no.

The bundle can contain image / data resources but also code, and there is a restriction guideline against running code that wasn't in the app when it was reviewed. If you're just loading image / data resources then you'll probably be fine. Code resources, you might get through review but would likely be pulled if found out.

Comment: We are looking to create xib files remotely (ie layout), however all the code would be inside the main project.  We are wondering if that would get through.

Comment: *Probably*. I guess it would be dependant upon how it's presented in the app. Why does it need to be downloadable? Best to ask Apple, they hold all the keys...